# AWS apache Forbidden error in apache : You don't have permission to access /icgd/ on this server

Tags: apache-2.2, amazon-web-services

i am trying with aws free tier. i have installed apache using yum.

Now i can access webserver from browser.

webroot is /var/www/html

i placed an index.html in /var/www/html and the same is working in browser

if i put a folder named icgd containing and index.html is is not getting ends with forbidden error.

is it assosiated with folder file permission (chown and chmod);if so kindly provide the command to resolve that.